# MVC Catch All route not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, try-catch

My first route:

```
  //  Should work for /Admin, /Admin/Index, /Admin/listArticles
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Admin",                                              // Route name
      "Admin/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
  );
```

is not resolving the route(I use [Phil Haack's Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)) and even the last route, "Catch All" route does not work:

```
  //Maps any completely invalid routes to ErrorController.NotFound
  routes.MapRoute("Catch All", "{*path}",
      new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
  );
```

If I go to `/Admin/listArticles` it works but `/Admin` gives me `Error 403.15 "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."` That points me to the idea that no routing is used as it looks for a physical file in a directory?

This is a simple low-level route problem but I cannot get it to work and everybody gives me links to read (yes I know MSDN is out there) but no real answers. I have researched routes and have tried but I am posting this because I cannot get it to work, any help, answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net MVC Routing Catchall not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318886/net-mvc-routing-catchall-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you have added this route below the default route, all custom routes should be added above default route.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was that I had a route called /Admin and I wrote my error log to a directory /Admin/Error It seems that there is no overload to specify if the route should be resolved or if it is part of a physical directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS 6.0?  If so it'll need to look like...

```
  //  Should work for /Admin, /Admin/Index, /Admin/listArticles
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Admin",                                              // Route name
      "Admin.mvc/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
  );
```

Where you need to [set mvc as an application extension](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)