# Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need an implementation where I can get infinite parameters on my ASP.NET Controller. It will be better if I give you an example :

Let's assume that I will have following urls :

```
example.com/tag/poo/bar/poobar
example.com/tag/poo/bar/poobar/poo2/poo4
example.com/tag/poo/bar/poobar/poo89
```

As you can see, it will get infinite number of tags after `example.com/tag/` and slash will be a delimiter here.

On the controller I would like to do this :

```
foreach(string item in paramaters) { 

    //this is one of the url paramaters
    string poo = item;

}
```

Is there any known way to achieve this? How can I get reach the values from controller? With `Dictionary<string, string>` or `List<string>`?

> **NOTE :**
>
> The question is not well explained IMO but I tried my best to fit it.
>   in. Feel free to tweak it

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Name", "tag/{*tags}", new { controller = ..., action = ... });

ActionResult MyAction(string tags) {
    foreach(string tag in tags.Split("/")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, looks like so neat. gonna give it a try.

Comment: what is the role of {*tags} there? Especially, *.

Comment: That's a catch-all parameter.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern

Comment: so, can we use all wildcard parameters on ASP.NET MVC framework like that or just *?

Comment: Huh? `*` means catch-all.  I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @tugberk: You can only use * and it always has to be the first character of a catch-all parameter. It is not a wildcard character in any way shape or form. It just means that this route parameter will catch everything from that point on in your URL.

Comment: The direct link to the "Handling a variable number of segments" section is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc668201(v=vs.140)#handling-a-variable-number-of-segments-in-a-url-pattern

Answer (score 26):

The catch all will give you the raw string. If you want a more elegant way to handle the data, you could always use a custom route handler.

```
public class AllPathRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    private readonly string key;

    public AllPathRouteHandler(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var allPaths = requestContext.RouteData.Values[key] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allPaths))
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values[key] = allPaths.Split('/');
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Register the route handler.

```
routes.Add(new Route("tag/{*tags}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Tag",
                    action = "Index",
                }),
        new AllPathRouteHandler("tags")));
```

Get the tags as a array in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] tags)
{
    // do something with tags
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

That's called [catch-all](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+catch-all):

```
tag/{*tags}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone is coming to this with MVC in .NET 4.0, you need to be careful **where** you define your routes. I was happily going to `global.asax` and adding routes as suggested in these answers (and in other tutorials) and getting nowhere.  My routes all just defaulted to `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Adding further segments to the URL gave me a 404 error. Then I discovered the RouteConfig.cs file in the App_Start folder.  It turns out this file is called by `global.asax` in the `Application_Start()` method. So, in .NET 4.0, make sure you add your custom routes there. [This article](http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2012/06/23/ASPNET-MVC-4-Where-Have-All-The-Globalasax-Routes-Gone.aspx) covers it beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

in asp .net core you can use * in routing
for example

[HTTPGet({*id})]

this code can multi parameter or when using send string with slash use them to get all parameters