# Regarding ASP.NET routing in WebForm & Asterisk sign

Tags: webforms, asp.net-routing

I saw people use asterisk sign at the time of routing in webform. i just do not understand the importance of Asterisk sign like below one

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
  "View Category",               // Route name
  "Categories/{*CategoryName}",  // Route URL
  "~/CategoryProducts.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
);
```

what is the meaning of asterisk sign and also tell me what kind of situation i should use asterisk sign like above.

```
"Categories/{*CategoryName}"
```

it would be better if anyone come with small sample code of using Asterisk sign just to show the importance & use of asterisk sign in real life apps.

Comment: "Astrix"? Is this via google translate? :) The [star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) is a wild-card, useful for constructing catch-all routes, for example. Covered in *any* ASP.NET MVC tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called catch all route mapping. See the below question as well :

[Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route)

Answer (score 13):

Since this was the first resource Google returned me for variable number of parameters I added below example from MSDN so future readers would find the solution here.

> The following example shows a route pattern that matches an unknown number of segments.

```
query/{queryname}/{*queryvalues}
```

**Case 1**

*URL* :
/query/select/bikes/onsale

*Resolved Parameter Values:*

- queryname = "select"
- queryvalues = "bikes/onsale"

---

**Case 2**

*URL* :
/query/select/bikes

*Resolved Parameter Values:*

- queryname = "select"
- queryvalues = "bikes"

---

**Case 3**

*URL* :
/query/select

*Resolved Parameter Values:*

- queryname = "select"
- queryvalues = Empty string

---

Reference:
[MSDN: Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_5)

Comment: this answer is clearer and easier to understand than the accepted one!