# ASP.NET MVC Routing with multiple optional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a situation on a single page web application. I use address information on the client to determine what data to load. I would like to be able to have url's like the following all direct to the Index action method on the HomeController.

```
http://mysite.com/Home/Index/Value/23/Another/34
http://mysite.com/Home/Index/Value/23/Another/34/StillAnother/45
```

In that controller method I would like a list of parameters such as:

```
{"Value", "23", "Another", "34"}
{"Value", "23", "Another", "34", "StillAnother", "45"}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single page web application doesn't mean having a single Controller and Action so I hope that's not what you're after. If you're just trying to bind additional URL parameters, then it is easily accomplished using routing. Take a look at this question: [Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route)