# Missing routing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I registered a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Journals",
    "Journals/{year}/{month}/{id}",
    new {
        controller = "Journals",
        action = "Get",
        year = UrlParameter.Optional,
        month = UrlParameter.Optional,
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Get(int? year, int? month, int? id)
```

Later in view (just to check):

```
@Url.Action("Get", "Journals")
@Url.Action("Get", "Journals", new { year = 2013 })
@Url.Action("Get", "Journals", new { year = 2013, month = 4 })
@Url.Action("Get", "Journals", new { year = 2013, month = 4, id = 1 })
```

And result is:

```
/Journals
/Journals
/Journals/2013/4
/Journals/2013/4/1
```

So the 2nd URL missed the parameter. What's wrong?

Comment: A useful tool for these situations is Phil Haack's route debugger: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more than 1 continuous optional route parameters.. as it cannot understand which one is missing..

the 2013 in  ***/Journals/2013*** could be interpreted as either a `year` or a `month` or an `id`

See [Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route) for a workaround using a catch-all route parameter.