# How do I set a route for a URL pattern in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a situation where I am pulling a web page from a 3rd party source and replacing all the links with links to my own page then displaying it with a Response.Write.

So, for example, the page I'm pulling might have:

```
<a href="http://www.thirdparty.com/a/b/c.html">Click Here!</a>
```

I modify this to

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/x/b/c.html">Click Here!"</a>
```

However, if they press Click Here, it's not routing to my controller.  I'm assuming because /b isn't in my route table.

How do I set up my route so that http://www.mysite.com/x ALWAYS goes to a specific controller, regardless of what comes after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Infinite URL Parameters for ASP.NET MVC Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route)

Looks like you can do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "x",
    url: "x/{*tags}",
    defaults: new { controller = "x", action = "Index" }
);
```

The {*tags} lets you specify an unlimited number of /'s.