# Using unlimited arguments (like a parms array) in routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.Net MVC, is it possible to define to a route that there may be an unknown number of arguments? For example assuming the following code:

```
public void Sample(params String[] args) {}
```

Can we mimic the same concept in a route like `[Route("Product/{id}")]` so that we get the following result working:

```
 /Product/PID_01/PID_02/PID_03,....
```

Comment: You could have a catch-all route - refer [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515644/infinite-url-parameters-for-asp-net-mvc-route)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: If we have more arguments like `Product/{Group}/{id}` then if catching all arguments, how can you tell which is which. I mean would the param argument be represented in form an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using [catch-all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern) route:

```
[Route("foo/{group}/{*id}")]
public IActionResult Foo(string group, string id)
{
    var ids = id.Split('/');
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Then go to:

> http://yourapp/foo/Product/PID_01/PID_02/PID_03

You can also define a custom [`ModelBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) to avoid the splitting in the controller code.