# MVC RouteConfig "CatchAll" {*url} not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, catch-all

I am attempting to "catch all" 500 and 404 errors within my MVC application and I can't seem to grasp what is needed, even after reading all the articles and questions out there.

`Web.config` (this allows 500 errors to go to `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml`):

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
</system.web>
```

I've setup the `HomeController` to throw an error to test the above setup:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Testing errors
    throw new Exception("Exception");

    return View();
}
```

In my `Global.asax.cs`, I have the following to log the 500 errors:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();

    //Custom ExceptionLog
    new ExceptionLogHelper().Add("Application_Error", Response.Status, ex);
}
```

Now for the 404 errors:

In my `RouteConfig.cs`, I have the following routes, but can't seem to catch all 404s:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error",
            url: "Error/{code}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //  name: "Controllers",
        //  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //  defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Keep at bottom
        routes.MapRoute("CatchAll", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", name = "no-route-found", code = "404" });

    }
}
```

`CatchAll` at the bottom is doing a good job catching everything that does not match the preceeding routes.

I have a bunch more test scenarios, but one that is bugging me is the following UrlParameter:

```
http://localhost:64275/does/not/exist/
```

The above URL is essentially `http://localhost:64275/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

I don't have a Controller named `does`, and I thought that `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` would default to the `Home` controller with Action of `Index` if no Controller was matched.

Another example that works:

```
http://localhost:64275/a/a/a/a/ (because it has 4 parts, not 3 or less)
```

Can someone explain where I might be going wrong? ...and what I am not understanding?

Should I be implementing something like this: [.Net MVC Routing Catchall not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318886/net-mvc-routing-catchall-not-working) (Darin Dimitrov's answer)

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError500");

            if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                routeData.Values["action"] = "HttpError404";
            }

        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Clear();
        IController errorController = new ErrorController();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    }
}
```

Comment: `and I thought that` You thought wrong. It doesn't work like that. It matched the pattern, so it tries to use the `does` controller. It doesn't factor whether or not `DoesController` exists in the decision making process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that the default route is being hit in the `http://localhost:64275/does/not/exist/` case. But, routing doesn't have any expensive Reflection calls built in to ensure the controller exists before attempting to create it.

However, you can intervene by making your own custom `IControllerFactory` that knows what to do when MVC can't locate the controller instance that is specified in the route.

### NotFoundControllerFactory.cs

```
public class NotFoundControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        // If controller not found it will be null, so we want to take control
        // of the request and send it to the ErrorController.NotFound method.
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, typeof(ErrorController));
        }

        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

`DefaultControllerFactory` accepts the controller as a string and then attempts to resolve the controller name to a type. If it can't the type is `null` when it calls `GetControllerInstance(RequestContext, Type)`. So, all we have to do is check whether the type is `null` and then rewrite our request so it instantiates the `ErrorController` and calls the `NotFound` action method.

### Usage

You just need to register the controller factory with MVC at startup.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NotFoundControllerFactory());
```

Then to tie everything together, your `NotFound` action method should set the status code to 404.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        Response.StatusDescription = "404 Not Found";

        return View();
    }
}
```

As for action methods, MVC *does* respond with a 404 Not Found if the action does not exist on a controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've had limited testing with this, but I believe this will work as a clean solution for my project!